# Getting error cannot create active X component in VB .NET 2017

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use

```
Dim obj as Object
obj = CreateObject("EXTRA.System") ' this line giving error
```

Using windows 10 64 bit system but always I get error cannot create active X component. And same code is working fine on windows 7. Please suggest.

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Is that ActiveX control registered on the Win10 machine?

Comment: Hi Rich, as I tried create Excel.Application object that works fine. But only Extra.System create issue.

Comment: Yes as I checked activex control is registered